# Rails Associations: with self through second model

Tags: activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models Classification and ClassificationRelationships. I want to create a hierarchy of classifications using supperclass and subclass so that each classification can have many subclasses but only one superclass.

my migrations look like this

```
class CreateClassifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :classifications do |t|
      t.string :symbol
      t.string :title
      t.integer :level

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :classifications, :symbol
    add_index :classifications, :level
  end
end

class CreateClassificationRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :classification_relationships do |t|
      t.integer :superclass_id
      t.integer :subclass_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :classification_relationships, :superclass_id
    add_index :classification_relationships, :subclass_id
    add_index :classification_relationships, [:superclass_id, :subclass_id], unique: true, name: 'unique_relationship'
  end
end
```

so far with my models I have

```
class ClassificationRelationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :superclass, :class_name => "Classification"
    belongs_to :subclass,   :class_name => "Classification"
end

class Classification < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :classification_relationships
    has_many :subclasses, through => :classification_relationships
    has_one  :superclass, through => :classification_relationships
end
```

I read quite a few other posts but am still unsure how to finish the associations. I am pretty sure I need to specify the foreign keys but am not clear on how I should do that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `ClassificationRelationship`.
All you need is for `Classification` to have a `parent_id` which, in the root instances, is allowed to be null.

Add:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Classification', foreign_key: :parent_id
def children
  Classification.where(:parent_id => self.id)
end
```

Some operations will not be optimal. e.g. Find all descendants. That's because this will require repeated queries to find children, their children, etc...
This may not be a concern for you.
If it is, I recommend storing a `path` as such:

```
after_create :set_path
def set_path
  path = parent ? "#{parent.path}#{self.id}/" : "#{self.id}/"
  self.update_attributes!(:path => path)
end
```

Then you can do things like:

```
def descendants
    Classification.where("classifications.path LIKE '#{self.path}%' AND classifications.path <> '#{self.path}'")
end
```

Of course, make sure path is indexed if you'll be doing queries like that.

Comment: Initially I had thought of something like this but I thought the queries would be more natural with the second relationship model between them. Thoughts?

Comment: I've offered a way to get exactly what you asked for with less database tables. The model is enforced by the database. A join table is for a many-to-many relationship. If you explain, perhaps with code examples, what "more  natural" means, then I can reconsider.

Comment: I think I was just misreading some of the railsguides. This will defenetly work. There is a section of the [railsguides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) that helped clear things up for me about self join associations(2.10 for reference). In addition though they add a has_many association that I think might take the place of the children method.